# SharePoint 2013 Search Results Trim Duplicates- Does full crawl is required

Tags: sharepoint-online

I just disabled the duplicate trimming in SharePoint 2013.

Is a Full Crawl required so that all the duplicates are removed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you do this change for a search web part, no need to do a full crawl.

Below article provides the reasons of when to do a full crawl, you can refer to it:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/plan-crawling-and-federation#Plan_full_crawl